# Problème with media queries that does not activate

Tags: css, media-queries

I train my CSS by making models of site or others already created. Currently, I am training with media queries and I have a problem is that it does not apply.

Before posting this message I created a simple page with a div containing two to see how the breakpoints worked and I got there but on this page I can't.

Could you tell me why nothing is happening?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no" />
    <!-- displays site properly based on user's device -->

    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="./images/favicon-32x32.png" />
    <style>
      * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }

      body {
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
        margin: 0 auto;
        background: linear-gradient(hsl(273, 75%, 66%), hsl(240, 73%, 65%));
        font-family: "Kumbh Sans", sans-serif;
        font-weight: 400;
        font-size: 14px;
      }

      p {
        width: 350px;
        color: hsl(237, 12%, 33%);
        font-size: 12px;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
        padding-top: -7px;
      }

      h1 {
        font-weight: 700;
        color: hsl(238, 29%, 16%);
        margin-bottom: 15px;
        font-size: 31px;
        letter-spacing: 2px;
      }

      .wrapper {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
      }

      .container {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
      }

      .box {
        background-color: white;
        border-radius: 23px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-around;
        align-items: center;
        width: 920px;
        height: 510px;
        overflow: hidden;
        margin-right: 191px;
      }

      .leftSide {
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
      }

      .svgCube {
        position: relative;
        left: 60px;
        top: 45px;
        z-index: 800;
      }

      .svgWoman {
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        right: 85px;
      }

      .rightSide {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: transparent;
        margin-top: -20px;
        margin-left: 3px;
      }

      .hiddenElement {
        display: none;
      }

      .divider {
        width: 335px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid hsl(240, 5%, 91%);
      }

      .btnFaq {
        width: 335px;
        font-family: "Kumbh Sans", sans-serif;
        font-weight: 400;
        font-size: 14px;
        background-color: white;
        border: none;
        color: hsl(237, 12%, 33%);
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content: space-between;
        align-items: center;
        padding-top: 22px;
        padding-bottom: 15px;
      }

      .btnFaq:hover {
        color: hsl(14, 88%, 65%);
      }

      @media only screen and (min-with: 300px) and (max-with: 850px) {
        .container {
          flex-direction: column;
        }

        .box {
          flex-direction: column;
          flex-wrap: wrap;
          width: 80vw;
          height: 60vh;
        }
      }

    </style>

    <title>Frontend Mentor | FAQ Accordion Card</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Kumbh+Sans:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="container">
        <svg class="svgCube" width="191" height="184" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
          <defs>
            <filter x="-97.9%" y="-76.3%" width="295.8%" height="313.7%" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" id="a">
              <feOffset dy="25" in="SourceAlpha" result="shadowOffsetOuter1" />
              <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="25" in="shadowOffsetOuter1" result="shadowBlurOuter1" />
              <feColorMatrix values="0 0 0 0 0.209139076 0 0 0 0 0.0691446444 0 0 0 0 0.478091033 0 0 0 0.497159091 0" in="shadowBlurOuter1" />
            </filter>
            <path id="b" d="M0 27.756v53.87l41.968 24.035 47.387-28.025v-53.87" />
          </defs>
          <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
            <g transform="translate(50.93 2.125)">
              <use fill="#000" filter="url(#a)" xlink:href="#b" />
              <use fill="#FF9271" xlink:href="#b" />
            </g>
            <path fill="#DF5C34" fill-rule="nonzero" d="M92.899 53.917v53.87l47.387-28.026v-53.87z" />
            <path fill="#F47B56" fill-rule="nonzero" d="M50.93 29.88L99.624 2.126l40.662 23.767-47.387 28.025z" />
            <path d="M94.013 14.49a25.942 25.942 0 0114.207 3.129c2.486 1.462 3.844 2.988 4.036 4.579.192 1.59-.628 2.975-2.562 4.143a9.115 9.115 0 01-2.985 1.18c-.869.205-1.76.295-2.652.269l-.974-.077c.091.217.151.446.18.68a3.132 3.132 0 01-.513 1.552 5.704 5.704 0 01-2.1 2.065 12.633 12.633 0 01-6.7 1.77 13.247 13.247 0 01-6.957-1.757c-1.999-1.18-3.023-2.566-3.1-4.156a4.49 4.49 0 012.562-4.015 8.488 8.488 0 012.357-1.013 9.175 9.175 0 012.037-.346h.705l-1.282-.77 3.6-2.244 8.34 4.912a4.377 4.377 0 004.15 0c1.769-1.103 1.137-2.552-1.895-4.348a19.261 19.261 0 00-10.556-2.347 21.67 21.67 0 00-11.018 3.168c-3.023 1.89-4.522 4.143-4.496 6.76 0 2.564 1.601 4.848 4.714 6.682a21.015 21.015 0 0011.146 2.655 20.926 20.926 0 0011.017-2.925 12.353 12.353 0 003.062-2.565 5.683 5.683 0 001.28-2.18l.18-.808 4.753.269c.008.145.008.29 0 .436a8.216 8.216 0 01-.346 1.154 8.303 8.303 0 01-.82 1.72 11.912 11.912 0 01-1.69 2 15.952 15.952 0 01-2.755 2.13 25.602 25.602 0 01-9.326 3.36 35.176 35.176 0 01-10.877.192 24.896 24.896 0 01-9.339-3.053 12.127 12.127 0 01-5.304-5.566 8.192 8.192 0 010-6.593 12.692 12.692 0 015.266-5.759 28.966 28.966 0 0114.655-4.284zm4.663 13.262c-.17-.891-.77-1.64-1.601-2.001a6.579 6.579 0 00-3.33-.911 5.619 5.619 0 00-3.101.795 2.283 2.283 0 00-1.281 2.001c.117.89.69 1.654 1.512 2.014a6.54 6.54 0 003.394.86 6.092 6.092 0 003.254-.847 2.065 2.065 0 001.205-1.911" fill="#3E2928" fill-rule="nonzero" />
          </g>
        </svg>
        <div class="box">
          <div class="leftSide">
            <svg class="svgWoman" width="472" height="359" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
              <defs>
                <linearGradient x1="61.181%" y1="36.82%" x2="40.788%" y2="55.54%" id="a">
                  <stop stop-color="#78B46A" offset="0%" />
                  <stop stop-color="#7F3500" offset="3%" />
                  <stop stop-color="#FFF" offset="100%" />
                </linearGradient>
                <linearGradient x1="82.186%" y1="28.519%" x2="29.852%" y2="62.464%" id="b">
                  <stop stop-color="#78B46A" offset="0%" />
                  <stop stop-color="#7F3500" offset="3%" />
                  <stop stop-color="#FFF" offset="100%" />
                </linearGradient>
                <linearGradient x1="80.66%" y1="21.864%" x2="21.557%" y2="66.62%" id="c">
                  <stop stop-color="#78B46A" offset="0%" />
                  <stop stop-color="#7F3500" offset="3%" />
                  <stop stop-color="#FFF" offset="100%" />
                </linearGradient>
                <linearGradient x1="81.016%" y1="60.589%" x2="67.462%" y2="55.277%" id="d">
                  <stop stop-color="#FFF" stop-opacity="0" offset="0%" />
                  <stop stop-color="#DC841E" offset="99%" />
                </linearGradient>
                <linearGradient x1="82.183%" y1="27.537%" x2="29.857%" y2="62.324%" id="e">
                  <stop stop-color="#78B46A" offset="0%" />
                  <stop stop-color="#7F3500" offset="3%" />
                  <stop stop-color="#FFF" offset="100%" />
                </linearGradient>
              </defs>
              <g fill-rule="nonzero" fill="none">
                <path d="M229.018 355.203L9.313 225.211c-6.995-3.938-12.99-10.39-6.175-14.622L223.625 83.367c3.305-2.052 8.327-3.399 11.696-1.437l230.595 134.007c6.994 4.066 8.25 15.392 1.28 19.496L257.972 354.998a29.178 29.178 0 01-28.953.205z" fill="#5B36A0" />
                <path d="M229.018 349.203L9.313 219.211c-6.995-3.938-12.99-10.39-6.175-14.622L223.625 77.367c3.305-2.052 8.327-3.399 11.696-1.437l230.595 134.007c6.994 4.066 8.25 15.392 1.28 19.496L257.972 348.998a29.178 29.178 0 01-28.953.205z" fill="#6862E6" />
                <path d="M247.133 177.693L203.78 202.46s66.783 40.8 80.439 46.546l24.968-35.913" fill="url(#a)" opacity=".25" style="mix-blend-mode: multiply" />
                <path d="M232.157 296.513l-43.365-24.715-43.364 24.767s22.585 13.8 44.171 26.473c13.708-9.71 27.428-19.521 42.558-26.525z" fill="url(#b)" opacity=".25" style="mix-blend-mode: multiply" />
                <path d="M138.728 143.883l-27.505 15.712s2.331 14.404 15.988 20.15l36.01-23.087" fill="url(#c)" opacity=".46" style="mix-blend-mode: multiply" />
                <ellipse fill="#68E1FD" cx="152.192" cy="147.898" rx="16.59" ry="11.697" />
                <ellipse fill="#974C26" cx="152.179" cy="140.997" rx="12.426" ry="5.092" />
                <path d="M151.73 132.506c0-2.296-.076-4.591-.256-6.887-.051-.599-.106-1.193-.166-1.783l-.128-1.167c0-.347-.18-1.283-.18-1.193-.077-.47-.158-.936-.243-1.398a54.855 54.855 0 00-8.865-21.715 31.778 31.778 0 00-2.473 12.71c0 1.284.103 2.566.205 3.772v.757c.103.615.218 1.282.346 1.846a50.222 50.222 0 001.96 6.888 41.928 41.928 0 002.678 6.003 82.454 82.454 0 003.676 6.349 90.88 90.88 0 002.985 4.425c.308-2.86.449-5.734.461-8.607zm-6.52-25.819a2.067 2.067 0 000-.897c.316.324.628.658.935 1a2.84 2.84 0 00-.948-.103h.013z" fill="#999A1C" />
                <path d="M155.996 134.276a65.015 65.015 0 003.498-5.938c.282-.53.555-1.06.82-1.59l.525-1.065.5-1.103.55-1.283a54.876 54.876 0 004.266-23.087 31.728 31.728 0 00-8.967 9.363 45.938 45.938 0 00-1.858 3.284l-.256.474-.064.206c-.243.577-.487 1.154-.717 1.744a50.22 50.22 0 00-2.063 6.862 41.95 41.95 0 00-.986 6.503 77.621 77.621 0 00-.333 7.323c0 1.911 0 3.656.115 5.336 1.704-2.27 3.42-4.605 4.97-7.029zm8.456-25.254c.2-.226.349-.493.435-.783.094.445.175.873.244 1.283-.2-.2-.43-.368-.68-.5z" fill="#999A1C" />
                <path d="M155.907 139.997a64.687 64.687 0 003.843-2.078l.96-.59.629-.398.615-.436.717-.526a34.464 34.464 0 009.736-11.069 19.928 19.928 0 00-7.84 2.168c-.705.36-1.384.757-2.063 1.167l-.294.18-.103.09-.948.705a31.541 31.541 0 00-3.33 3.04 26.351 26.351 0 00-2.627 3.193 83.516 83.516 0 00-2.562 3.848 55.792 55.792 0 00-1.653 2.925c1.653-.693 3.306-1.411 4.92-2.22zm12.708-10.902a1.28 1.28 0 00.487-.283c-.094.274-.196.543-.308.808a1.797 1.797 0 00-.179-.513v-.012zM151.73 132.506c0-2.296-.076-4.591-.256-6.887-.051-.599-.106-1.193-.166-1.783l-.128-1.167c0-.347-.18-1.283-.18-1.193-.077-.47-.158-.936-.243-1.398a54.855 54.855 0 00-8.865-21.715 31.778 31.778 0 00-2.473 12.71c0 1.284.103 2.566.205 3.772v.757c.103.615.218 1.282.346 1.846a50.222 50.222 0 001.96 6.888 41.928 41.928 0 002.678 6.003 82.454 82.454 0 003.676 6.349 90.88 90.88 0 002.985 4.425c.308-2.86.449-5.734.461-8.607zm-6.52-25.819a2.067 2.067 0 000-.897c.316.324.628.658.935 1a2.84 2.84 0 00-.948-.103h.013z" fill="#999A1C" />
                <path d="M155.996 134.276a65.015 65.015 0 003.498-5.938c.282-.53.555-1.06.82-1.59l.525-1.065.5-1.103.55-1.283a54.876 54.876 0 004.266-23.087 31.728 31.728 0 00-8.967 9.363 45.938 45.938 0 00-1.858 3.284l-.256.474-.064.206c-.243.577-.487 1.154-.717 1.744a50.22 50.22 0 00-2.063 6.862 41.95 41.95 0 00-.986 6.503 77.621 77.621 0 00-.333 7.323c0 1.911 0 3.656.115 5.336 1.704-2.27 3.42-4.605 4.97-7.029zm8.456-25.254c.2-.226.349-.493.435-.783.094.445.175.873.244 1.283-.2-.2-.43-.368-.68-.5z" fill="#999A1C" />
                <path d="M155.907 139.997a64.687 64.687 0 003.843-2.078l.96-.59.629-.398.615-.436.717-.526a34.464 34.464 0 009.736-11.069 19.928 19.928 0 00-7.84 2.168c-.705.36-1.384.757-2.063 1.167l-.294.18-.103.09-.948.705a31.541 31.541 0 00-3.33 3.04 26.351 26.351 0 00-2.627 3.193 83.516 83.516 0 00-2.562 3.848 55.792 55.792 0 00-1.653 2.925c1.653-.693 3.306-1.411 4.92-2.22zm12.708-10.902a1.28 1.28 0 00.487-.283c-.094.274-.196.543-.308.808a1.797 1.797 0 00-.179-.513v-.012z" fill="#999A1C" />
                <path d="M264.35 168.022l-23.994 11.543a5.53 5.53 0 00-.384 9.76l56.867 33.22a5.518 5.518 0 007.43-1.782l13.823-21.523" fill="#A1482D" />
                <path d="M394.854 112.344L203.524 1.962a8.626 8.626 0 00-8.626.01 8.644 8.644 0 00-4.312 7.48v114.833a7.184 7.184 0 003.587 6.22L398.146 248.39a4.62 4.62 0 004.632.003 4.631 4.631 0 002.312-4.018V130.018a20.398 20.398 0 00-10.236-17.674z" fill="#F47B56" />
                <path d="M203.537 10.646l185.552 106.88a13.034 13.034 0 016.52 11.286v86.076a4.708 4.708 0 01-2.344 4.065 4.697 4.697 0 01-4.688.014L199.348 110.304a4.643 4.643 0 01-2.331-4.027V14.429c0-1.555.827-2.992 2.171-3.772a4.351 4.351 0 014.35-.011z" fill="#FFF" />
                <ellipse fill="#AB643C" transform="rotate(-10.9 280.738 168.465)" cx="280.738" cy="168.465" rx="4.036" ry="4.617" />
                <path fill="url(#d)" opacity=".32" d="M253.41 127.427l86.23 51.869 42.595-24.793-76.109-44.353" />
                <path d="M359.97 117.102l-93.224-56.91a3.225 3.225 0 00-3.278.028 3.233 3.233 0 00-1.565 2.884V95.53a3.4 3.4 0 001.627 2.924l93.212 55.704c.997.567 2.22.56 3.21-.02a3.22 3.22 0 001.594-2.79l.487-30.23a4.542 4.542 0 00-2.063-4.015z" fill="#E2AC00" />
                <path d="M337.667 133.789c3.343 4.681 9.223 5.99 13.118 2.937 3.894-3.053 4.343-9.324 1-13.993-3.345-4.669-9.225-5.99-13.12-2.937-3.894 3.052-4.342 9.311-.998 13.993z" fill="#FFF" />
                <path d="M328.52 111.318l-38.023-22.92a1.447 1.447 0 00-1.862.578 1.45 1.45 0 00.402 1.91l38.022 22.92a1.447 1.447 0 001.862-.578 1.45 1.45 0 00-.401-1.91zM326.957 120.63l-52.41-31.591a1.45 1.45 0 00-1.396 2.488l52.345 31.603a1.447 1.447 0 001.862-.578 1.45 1.45 0 00-.401-1.91v-.013z" fill="#F2F2F2" />
                <path d="M341.369 123.387L248.196 66.49a3.225 3.225 0 00-3.278.028 3.233 3.233 0 00-1.565 2.884v32.411a3.4 3.4 0 001.615 2.938l93.211 55.703c1.008.58 2.25.57 3.248-.025a3.22 3.22 0 001.569-2.848l.487-30.23a4.542 4.542 0 00-2.114-3.964z" fill="#F47B56" />
                <path d="M319.065 140.074c3.344 4.681 9.224 5.99 13.119 2.937 3.894-3.053 4.342-9.325.999-13.993-3.344-4.67-9.224-5.99-13.118-2.938-3.895 3.053-4.343 9.312-1 13.994z" fill="#FFF" />
                <path d="M309.918 117.602l-38.048-22.92a1.447 1.447 0 00-1.862.578 1.45 1.45 0 00.402 1.91l38.022 22.92a1.447 1.447 0 001.862-.578 1.45 1.45 0 00-.401-1.91h.025zM308.343 126.978l-52.397-31.642a1.447 1.447 0 00-1.862.579 1.45 1.45 0 00.402 1.91l52.409 31.59a1.447 1.447 0 001.862-.578 1.45 1.45 0 00-.402-1.91l-.012.051z" fill="#F2F2F2" />
                <path d="M317.99 127.21l-93.2-56.897a3.225 3.225 0 00-3.278.027 3.233 3.233 0 00-1.564 2.884v32.412a3.4 3.4 0 001.627 2.924l93.211 55.704c1.008.58 2.25.57 3.249-.026a3.22 3.22 0 001.568-2.847l.487-30.231a4.542 4.542 0 00-2.1-3.95z" fill="#68E1FD" />
                <path d="M317.99 127.21l-93.2-56.897a3.225 3.225 0 00-3.278.027 3.233 3.233 0 00-1.564 2.884v32.412a3.4 3.4 0 001.627 2.924l93.211 55.704c1.008.58 2.25.57 3.249-.026a3.22 3.22 0 001.568-2.847l.487-30.231a4.542 4.542 0 00-2.1-3.95z" fill="#68E1FD" />
                <path d="M295.673 143.896c3.343 4.681 9.224 5.99 13.118 2.937 3.895-3.053 4.343-9.325 1-13.993-3.344-4.669-9.225-5.99-13.119-2.937-3.894 3.052-4.304 9.311-1 13.993z" fill="#FFF" />
                <path d="M286.526 121.425l-38.035-22.92a1.447 1.447 0 00-1.862.578 1.45 1.45 0 00.401 1.91l38.023 22.92a1.447 1.447 0 001.862-.578 1.45 1.45 0 00-.402-1.91h.013zM284.95 130.75l-52.409-31.592a1.447 1.447 0 00-1.862.579 1.45 1.45 0 00.402 1.91l52.409 31.59a1.447 1.447 0 001.862-.578 1.45 1.45 0 00-.402-1.91z" fill="#F2F2F2" />
                <path d="M195.672 124.028a45.406 45.406 0 00-13.208 19.38c-4.638 12.827 6.956 33.784 6.956 33.784l18.038-14.3" fill="#FF8F6F" />
                <path d="M193.724 293.602l-4.893-2.706 1.28-7.003s7.29.692 7.93 3.283" fill="#003B94" />
                <path d="M195.518 293.5c1.102-.68 2.255-1.283 3.395-1.886 2.83-1.552 6.918-3.155 8.66-6.067a3.39 3.39 0 00-.23-3.848c-2.563-3.104-8.174 2.001-11.044-1.436-.563-.68-.832-11.467-.832-11.467l-10.915 2.95s-1.845 21.676-1.64 23.01c.205 1.334 3.959 2.566 3.959 2.566a9.666 9.666 0 003.151-1.283c1.14-.834.102-11.005 1.563-9.581 1.46 1.424 2.1 6.99 2.1 6.99.607.092 1.222.11 1.833.051z" fill="#F47B56" />
                <path d="M214.568 304.08l-4.894-2.667 1.28-7.003s7.29.693 7.93 3.283" fill="#003B94" />
                <path d="M216.412 303.978c1.102-.68 2.255-1.282 3.395-1.885 2.831-1.552 6.918-3.155 8.66-6.067a3.39 3.39 0 00-.23-3.848c-2.563-3.104-8.174 2.001-11.043-1.436-.564-.68-.833-11.467-.833-11.467l-10.915 2.95s-1.857 21.753-1.652 23.036c.205 1.282 3.958 2.565 3.958 2.565a9.666 9.666 0 003.152-1.283c1.14-.833.102-11.004 1.563-9.58 1.46 1.423 2.1 6.99 2.1 6.99a7.498 7.498 0 001.845.025z" fill="#F47B56" />
                <path d="M179.005 233.614l-3.216 43.058s5.125 7.08 22.304 3.142l.166-29.026M198.849 242.144c-.372 3.706 0 44.596 0 44.596s4.752 8.901 25.442 0l-.295-34.746" fill="#3E2928" />
                <path d="M177.403 247.838c1.41.975 1.896-4.04 3.37-3.18a83.77 83.77 0 0016.961 7.49h.128a1.165 1.165 0 011.576.577 89.585 89.585 0 0011.133 2.565c4.83.77 8.826-2.808 13.784-3.052 0-19.008.09-73.109-7.994-84.652l-23.918-8.055c-.115 1.975-11.606 15.314-11.325 31.578.32 18.328-2.062 35.618-2.472 41.351-.064.975-1.191 14.34-1.243 15.378z" fill="#3E2928" />
                <path d="M218.564 145.73l-2.203 21.804s-17.845.719-25.532-4.591v-18.496" fill="#FF8F6F" />
                <path d="M241.252 131.378l-1.819 2.488c.97-2.024 1.826-4.1 2.562-6.22.513-1.45-1.806-2.027-2.318-.578l-.27.744c.223-.77.432-1.543.628-2.322a1.195 1.195 0 10-2.319-.577 62.236 62.236 0 01-1.806 5.952 42.54 42.54 0 00.846-5.26c.154-1.525-2.242-1.461-2.383 0a37.916 37.916 0 01-1.076 5.965c0-.684-.064-1.368-.192-2.052a1.206 1.206 0 00-.5-.86 9.29 9.29 0 00-.23-.795 1.204 1.204 0 00-2.345.36l-.154 8.978c-.433.93-.999 1.795-1.678 2.565a41.64 41.64 0 013.331 2.565 34.337 34.337 0 012.716 2.565 65.716 65.716 0 002.216-2.924c.088-.075.166-.161.23-.257a255.44 255.44 0 016.611-9.337c.948-1.052-1.14-2.219-2.05-1z" fill="#FFB5A9" />
                <path d="M207.24 125.85s8.43 2.27 11.85 7.695a96.553 96.553 0 015.65 11.66l6.225-9.685s7.559 2.322 10.556 6.042c0 0-8.967 19.623-16.782 21.304-7.814 1.68-16.116-11.518-16.116-11.518s-1.716 5.515-1.383-.372" fill="#FF8F6F" />
                <path d="M212.595 146.82a17.097 17.097 0 01-5.342-7.618c-1.013-3.45.256-6.478 1.434-9.684a31.237 31.237 0 002.204-9.966c.102-3.36-.282-6.72-.513-10.069a.976.976 0 010-.436c-1.127-3.783-3.433-6.99-7.98-7.375-11.774-1-12.44 12.057-12.35 17.367.09 5.31.653 8.901-3.254 11.12-3.908 2.219-6.726 8.042-2.998 12.75 3.728 4.706.384 2.988-2.101 7.169-2.485 4.181-1.845 9.402 3.254 11.287 5.099 1.885 28.799-1.655 30.976-3.848a4.531 4.531 0 001.115-3.206 12.444 12.444 0 00-4.445-7.49z" fill="#007F68" />
                <path d="M224.176 39.132a18.805 18.805 0 013.33 9.748 6.419 6.419 0 01-1.088 4.553 2.624 2.624 0 01-3.178.552 4.906 4.906 0 01-1.716-1.154 5.989 5.989 0 01-1.102-1.398l-.307-.603a2.13 2.13 0 01-.308.436 2.24 2.24 0 01-1.05.449 3.186 3.186 0 01-1.896-.231 7.113 7.113 0 01-3.357-3.014 9.692 9.692 0 01-1.486-4.861 4.775 4.775 0 011.192-3.848 2.739 2.739 0 013.113-.488c.513.205.986.5 1.396.873.35.297.659.637.922 1.013l.23.41v-1.141l2.563 1 .256 7.209c.018.516.178 1.017.462 1.449.24.417.609.745 1.05.936 1.238.488 1.81-.581 1.717-3.206a13.889 13.889 0 00-2.473-7.247 12.136 12.136 0 00-5.675-4.848 4.774 4.774 0 00-5.33.68 7.252 7.252 0 00-2.062 5.925 15.3 15.3 0 002.562 7.696 11.817 11.817 0 005.47 5.13c.812.34 1.684.51 2.563.5a3.417 3.417 0 001.665-.307l.513-.283 1.55 2.886-.257.18a6.133 6.133 0 01-.755.359c-.41.177-.84.298-1.282.36a6.398 6.398 0 01-1.703 0 8.575 8.575 0 01-2.165-.552 14.093 14.093 0 01-5.125-3.771 22.36 22.36 0 01-3.971-6.208 19.027 19.027 0 01-1.64-6.888c-.138-2 .27-3.999 1.179-5.784a6.51 6.51 0 013.638-3.207 7 7 0 015.047.257 16.288 16.288 0 017.508 6.438zm-5.65 9.12c.42-.538.61-1.221.525-1.899a4.904 4.904 0 00-.679-2.372 3.255 3.255 0 00-1.55-1.411 1.395 1.395 0 00-1.576.205 2.35 2.35 0 00-.563 1.86c.029.846.28 1.669.73 2.385.37.652.94 1.165 1.627 1.463a1.28 1.28 0 001.486-.231M375.433 178.013a18.74 18.74 0 013.33 9.748 6.419 6.419 0 01-1.088 4.553 2.637 2.637 0 01-3.177.552 5.047 5.047 0 01-1.717-1.154 6.207 6.207 0 01-1.102-1.399l-.307-.602c-.087.156-.19.302-.308.436-.304.24-.666.395-1.05.449a3.071 3.071 0 01-1.883-.218 7.113 7.113 0 01-3.357-3.027 9.653 9.653 0 01-1.499-4.874 4.724 4.724 0 011.192-3.848 2.726 2.726 0 013.1-.487c.514.204.987.499 1.396.872.35.302.66.647.923 1.026l.243.41v-1.141l2.562.987.257 7.209c.022.515.181 1.015.46 1.449.242.417.61.745 1.051.936 1.281.488 1.807-.577 1.73-3.206a13.953 13.953 0 00-2.473-7.26 12.161 12.161 0 00-5.662-4.835 4.787 4.787 0 00-5.33.667 7.252 7.252 0 00-2.01 5.964 15.25 15.25 0 002.561 7.695 11.868 11.868 0 005.535 4.964 6.668 6.668 0 002.562.513 3.545 3.545 0 001.665-.308l.513-.282 1.55 2.886-.256.18a6.133 6.133 0 01-.756.359c-.412.17-.842.29-1.281.359a6.526 6.526 0 01-1.717 0 8.55 8.55 0 01-2.152-.564 14.093 14.093 0 01-5.125-3.759 22.41 22.41 0 01-3.97-6.22 18.988 18.988 0 01-1.64-6.888 11.003 11.003 0 011.178-5.772 6.562 6.562 0 013.638-3.219 7.09 7.09 0 015.06.257 16.315 16.315 0 017.354 6.592zm-5.65 9.12a2.567 2.567 0 00.538-1.899 4.865 4.865 0 00-.691-2.372 3.204 3.204 0 00-1.538-1.411 1.395 1.395 0 00-1.575.192 2.323 2.323 0 00-.577 1.86c.03.842.281 1.66.73 2.373.369.655.94 1.172 1.627 1.475a1.28 1.28 0 001.486-.218" fill="#F47B56" />
                <path d="M120.139 232.704L76.774 208l-43.351 24.754s24.122 15.083 45.709 27.756c13.707-9.697 25.89-20.791 41.007-27.807z" fill="url(#e)" opacity=".25" style="mix-blend-mode: multiply" />
              </g>
            </svg>
          </div>

          <div class="rightSide">
            <h1>FAQ</h1>

            <button onclick="toggleElement('btnFaq1')" class="btnFaq" id="btnFaq1">
              How many team members can I invite?
              <svg class="iconButton" width="10" height="7" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <path d="M1 .799l4 4 4-4" stroke="#F47B56" stroke-width="2" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" />
              </svg>
            </button>

            <p id="textRightSide1" class="hiddenElement">
              You can invite up to 2 additional users on the Free plan. There is
              no limit on team members for the Premium plan.
            </p>
            <div class="divider"></div>
            <button onclick="toggleElement('btnFaq2')" id="btnFaq2" class="btnFaq">
              What is the maximum file upload size?
              <svg class="iconButton" width="10" height="7" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <path d="M1 .799l4 4 4-4" stroke="#F47B56" stroke-width="2" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" />
              </svg>
            </button>
            <p id="textRightSide2" class="hiddenElement">
              No more than 2GB. All files in your account must fit your allotted
              storage space.
            </p>
            <div class="divider"></div>

            <button onclick="toggleElement('btnFaq3')" id="btnFaq3" class="btnFaq">
              How do I reset my password?
              <svg class="iconButton" width="10" height="7" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <path d="M1 .799l4 4 4-4" stroke="#F47B56" stroke-width="2" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" />
              </svg>
            </button>
            <p id="textRightSide3" class="hiddenElement">
              Click “Forgot password” from the login page or “Change password”
              from your profile page. A reset link will be emailed to you.
            </p>
            <div class="divider"></div>

            <button onclick="toggleElement('btnFaq4')" id="btnFaq4" class="btnFaq">
              Can I cancel my subscription?
              <svg class="iconButton" width="10" height="7" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <path d="M1 .799l4 4 4-4" stroke="#F47B56" stroke-width="2" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" />
              </svg>
            </button>
            <p id="textRightSide4" class="hiddenElement">
              Yes! Send us a message and we’ll process your request no questions
              asked.
            </p>
            <div class="divider"></div>

            <button onclick="toggleElement('btnFaq5')" id="btnFaq5" class="btnFaq">
              Do you provide additional support?
              <svg class="iconButton" width="10" height="7" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <path d="M1 .799l4 4 4-4" stroke="#F47B56" stroke-width="2" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" />
              </svg>
            </button>
            <p id="textRightSide5" class="hiddenElement">
              Chat and email support is available 24/7. Phone lines are open
              during normal business hours.
            </p>
            <div class="divider"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Refer the jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zqh3ra0u/2/

Comment: please add your code to this very post please :)

Comment: Could you please highlight what exactly you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read your code more attentively before asking, you wrote `with` instead of `width` in the `@media` rule.